# While deriving Coulomb's Law from Gauss' Law, the power of 'r' comes out to be exactly 2 while experiment shows that it differs about 10^(-16). Why?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, coulombs-law, laws-of-physics

While deriving Coulomb's Law from Gauss' Law, the power of 'r' comes out to be exactly 2 while experiment shows that it differs about 10^(-16). Why is it so?
I'm referring to the book 'Physics by Resnick, Halliday and Krane 5th edition'. Chapter 25 - Coulomb's Law [image]

Comment: Which experiments?

Comment: You should provide a link to the data that you are citing.  Is this within the error bounds?  One would expect it to be so.

Comment: As for the "derivation of Coulomb's law from Gauss' law"... that's not even good theory.

Comment: I'm referring to the book 'Physics by Resnick, Halliday and Krane 5th edition'. A derivation of Coulomb's Law is given from Gauss' Law and cited that the power of 'r' is not exactly 2.

Comment: I don't have that book and I can't comment on what Resnick, Halliday and Krane are writing there, but deriving Coulomb from anything but experiments is not good physics and making a claim that there is a deviation of the actual force from Coulomb's law (which, by definition has an integer exponent) without citing the precision experiment that found it is just not acceptable for a textbook.

Comment: Could you quote the section from the book in your question?

Comment: Experiment by Plimpton and Lawton in 1936 and Williams, Faller  and Hill in 1971.

Comment: That statement obviously means that the exponent with error is $2\pm 10^{-16}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misrepresented the citation in the book. The [5th edition](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HdHGumicfWQjRjTmw4NXA3LVE/view?pref=2&pli=1) page 757 discusses experiments with a hollow sphere and a solid sphere.

[image]

The experiments verify that the exponent is 2 within experimental error.

Comment: Okay. I thought from the language that the exponent actually differs from 2 but now I understand that it is experimental uncertainty. Thank You. ( I have 5th edition International Student version)